# Kill a forked process in a docker container make the container exit on Jenkins docker slave plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

I am using docker to do build and testing. During testing, my test cases will launch a separate process(mongod process) and after the test cases finish it will kill that process. During the whole test cases running time, the `mongod` process will be generated and killed many times. The problem I have is when the mongod process is killed, the docker container exits with the code 137. My docker file is below:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN sed -i -e 's/us.archive.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    openssh-client openssh-server rsync vim \
    dh-autoreconf libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev \
    && curl -OL https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.13.1.tar.gz \
    && tar -zxf v2.13.1.tar.gz && cd git-2.13.1 && make configure && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make all && make install && cd .. \
    && apt-get remove -y dh-autoreconf libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev \
    && rm -rf v2.13.1.tar.gz git-2.13.1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "unsafe-perm = true" > /root/.npmrc \
    && echo "Australia/Melbourne" > /etc/timezone 
    # && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs && npm install -g yarn

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    python \ 
    python-pip python-dev \
          && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && yarn global add node-gyp && pip install --upgrade pip && pip install setuptools


RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6 \
    && echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    mongodb-org \
    python-pip python-dev \
    && pip install mtools pymongo numpy \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER root
RUN adduser jenkins
RUN chmod 777 /home/jenkins
ADD ./.aws /home/jenkins/.aws
USER jenkins
```

I use below command to launch the `mongod` process:

```
mongod --dbpath /home/jenkins/.jenkins/data/db --logpath /home/jenkins/.jenkins/data/mongod.log --port 27017 --logappend --fork
```

There is no problem for me to run the project test cases locally. So I think this relates to docker. My docker is running in `CoreOS`. Version is:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```

This container is launched by `jenkins docker slave` plugin. After some investigation, it works fine if I launch the container manually by `docker run -it -d $NAME bash` but not work if the container launched by `Jenkins docker slave`. I wonder which launch command may cause this issue. How can I fix this issue without changing docker launcher command?

Below is the `docker inspect` output:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "81ffad4b15115077dda23c221eb8053915f41cdf0e75de4417d23f81df12f87f",
        "Created": "2017-07-28T01:08:40.598084613Z",
        "Path": "/trampoline",
        "Args": [
            "wait"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 14152,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-07-28T01:08:41.044051569Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:7d1e60ecf32337654f46c54b05e3db11f724f12c4f879ccd42c9566c59edc6b2",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/097e51587d94fa0282ee51f6b84c006a6a410aadb2891f24b25caf41a1d14f39/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/097e51587d94fa0282ee51f6b84c006a6a410aadb2891f24b25caf41a1d14f39/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/097e51587d94fa0282ee51f6b84c006a6a410aadb2891f24b25caf41a1d14f39/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/81ffad4b15115077dda23c221eb8053915f41cdf0e75de4417d23f81df12f87f/81ffad4b15115077dda23c221eb8053915f41cdf0e75de4417d23f81df12f87f-json.log",
        "Name": "/heuristic_ritchie",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:svirt_lxc_file_t:s0:c896,c995",
        "ProcessLabel": "system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c896,c995",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": [
            "a827e4666391224dc9b3e7f94ea3a7615fb5215c82de6a481289fa125bf9495f"
        ],
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "container:097e51587d94fa0282ee51f6b84c006a6a410aadb2891f24b25caf41a1d14f39",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [
                "097e51587d94fa0282ee51f6b84c006a6a410aadb2891f24b25caf41a1d14f39"
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "container:097e51587d94fa0282ee51f6b84c006a6a410aadb2891f24b25caf41a1d14f39",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": [
                "label=user:system_u",
                "label=role:system_r",
                "label=type:svirt_lxc_net_t",
                "label=level:s0:c896,c995"
            ],
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 4294967296,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 8589934592,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf2b1c63a0862bcc09c3a126e41b6658b60178ade943a8844780a24b01cf2f7c-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/be89c1495150690fd934ba56411d144f7de43d06d268fe4b2d0e12552bab6b31/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d222b270a29034ff81603a80776dd05a259369dcb721515bb2ad08039e9327f1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f1c10959b14c67f2776cd5696a8281f514a42505ec2e0aab759f8543f0e6eed/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/adfec4e3f9b8b1252520f8a56ee27d4cf5fb3f3a01dae344c9932f5bda7d732f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e350f5d2bcc4252a5f067eb72b5ad65c6c620178347373736e1308c35e0a17d3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ed71b40ecf304222f071b0ccfc14f10dbd7566de01d16ff80169dea80dd72d4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1b20e86eb201191ce6fd4d904f1bfd95fe3423bd6d083cd763c7995a518c9e23/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/35c6c2859ec66d741643c7f9ff47e8513504e7560ea63369f671b305a66edaa1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/50e277363a9f73f105e6a60edb47c257b04f8383e4575e0cb67e6d628148c305/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3163f8c2fc0c94623b3390178b5d9de9938d2e9399df0f0341384f8d0fc75761/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1dc179342c7786f88e98fd68f72dcb187d8524b203ce6122158cf68d94df3a3a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f3f749adb1ea12915a0bc1b6258682cbf7571288656325152784b02039b56fd1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/deb0c7c423d5f685db5213536810c71fae89fee553d830f6a7cfba3b29853097/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf2b1c63a0862bcc09c3a126e41b6658b60178ade943a8844780a24b01cf2f7c/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf2b1c63a0862bcc09c3a126e41b6658b60178ade943a8844780a24b01cf2f7c/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf2b1c63a0862bcc09c3a126e41b6658b60178ade943a8844780a24b01cf2f7c/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "46705245e5a0a71c14665c843a34ee349f19b4cc0efeed655e9b3575b0b83a3d",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/46705245e5a0a71c14665c843a34ee349f19b4cc0efeed655e9b3575b0b83a3d/_data",
                "Destination": "/home/jenkins/.jenkins",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "097e51587d94",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "10000:10000",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "TMPDIR=/home/jenkins/.jenkins/.tmp",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info",
                "NODE_VERSION=7.10.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=0.24.4"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/trampoline",
                "wait"
            ],
            "Image": "jenkins-mongo-3.4",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/home/jenkins/.jenkins",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "zhaoyi0113@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {}
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What command are you invoking the container with?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about the command. I am using `jenkins docker slave` plugin to launch the container. Is there something to do with the launch command?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have checked that it works fine if I launch it manually by `docker run -it -d NAME bash`. So the problem relates to the launcher command. Do you know which launcher command may cause this issue? How can I fix this issue without changing docker launcher command?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the mongod process as pid1, use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) instead.

So start mongodb using supervisor ( if it is needed at all and your test does not really start it itself ).

this way, your test can easily start / stop the process using:

`supervisorctl stop mongod` and start it again using `supervisorctl start mongod`

Stopping the mongod service will not exit the container, since supervisord is pid1

If you want the test to start it using the binary specifically and you do not need pid tracking and the connivence, you can use a busyscript as pid and then start the mongod process in the container using the tests.

A busyscript looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x

pid=0

# SIGTERM-handler
term_handler() {
  if [ $pid -ne 0 ]; then
    kill -SIGTERM "$pid"
    wait "$pid"
  fi
  exit 143; # 128 + 15 -- SIGTERM
}

# setup handlers
# on callback, kill the last background process, which is `tail -f /dev/null` and execute the specified handler
trap 'kill ${!}; term_handler' SIGTERM

echo "Started DW php code"
# wait forever
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done
```

Alternatively, a lot more effort but probably the dockish way would be, use to containers. One is your test-runner with a host-mounted docker socket. This one will run the test and start the mongod contaienr and kill at as you like, so basically the test will kill /rm mongod containers instead of the process itself - and then start the container again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the build scripts need to be run in other platforms, like windows, docker, mac. So I don't want to change the test cases. Is there a way to solve it in the docker side?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: Is there an other way to solve the problem which don't change the launching script? As you mentioned I need to launch it by `supervisorctl start mongod`. This will impact my test scripts and I don't want to change this.

Comment: as i told you, use 2 containers then. One is the test-runner, starting a mongdb container and killing it, as often as you like.

you seem to migrate to docker but you do not want to adopt it - that will end very satisfying for you

Comment: If I do a separate docker container, I have to update test scripts to make the change. And it works fine if I launch my docker container manually but doesn't work on using jenkins docker slave plugin. I think jenkins plugin has some special launch command. I will tag a jenkins plugin for this question. Thanks for your help anyway.